# Эмулятор от Android Studio - пропала панель с кнопками событий

Tags: android-studio, настройка, настройки, эмулятор

Добрый день!
Еще неделю назад, при запуске эмулятора андроид входящего в комплект Android Studio (2.2 preview 3), справа от окна эмулятора появлялась панель с кнопками (громкость, питание, вращение экрана и тд, в том числе была кнопка к доступу эмулирования событий (входящий звонок, входящее смс, подкл/откл питания и тд).
В какой-то момент (возможно после обновлений) данная панель с кнопками пропала. 
Подскажите, в каких настройках ее можно включить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю это баг Preview версии, если не хотите откатываться то могу посоветовать использовать hotkeys (F1 -> Help -> вкладка Keyboard Shortcuts).

Comment: Согласен, возможно проблема из-за Preview версии, только не понял что дает вкладка Keyboard Shortcuts

Comment: @x555xx горячие клавиши тех функций которые были на панели.

Comment: мне кажется горячие клавиши не решат проблему, т.к. панель кнопок открывала экран с параметрами (например отправить смс, эмулировать входящий звонок и тд)

Comment: @x555xx я сейчас не могу посмотреть, но если мне не изменяет память, то клавиша F1 открывает тот же самый экран в котором можно эмулировать звонок и т.д.

Comment: ступил вначале, нажал F1 в студии. сейчас уже проверить не удалось, перед вашим ответом нажал обновить с 3 до Preview 4 и проблема пропала. Но F1 как раз отображает нужное окно.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, логичным способом вернуть былые функции - это отказаться от preview версий и пользоваться стабильным каналом, для обновления. Версии из стабильного канала гарантируют хорошую и стабильную работу, нежели preview или beta.